# Update a varchar field with null value

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a field `clube varchar(50)` that is by default NULL, and it it's not `notnull` so it accepts null values. What I need to know is, if I have a value already on this field and I want to make an `Update` and set it's value with `null`, how would I do that?
I tried to set `null` the value of a `string` but didnt worked.

IF some condition become true, I want to set this field as `NULL` by an `Update`.

And as obvious, if the condition become false, I will pass a value and NOT `null` value. So I need to do it using `MySqlcommand Parameter`.  Like:

```
sql = "UPDATE usuarios SET nome = @nome";
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Parameter.Add(New MySqlParameter("@nome", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = `variable`;
```

if the condition is `true` = `variable = null` else `variable != null`.

Comment: it's so easy to make a `downvote`... Now help with answers nothing !

Comment: I agree that this should not be closed. I think people think it needs to be posted on [dba.se], but this is just in the gray area which fits everywhere. It should not get closed IMO. (yes I know I voted 'leave closed', that was a mis click from me, I hope this message will make other people to vote for 'reopen')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer I found:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@nomeclube", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(usr.Nome_Clube) ? (object)usr.Nome_Clube : DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 4):

To set the value to null:

```
cmd.Parameter.Add(New MySqlParameter("@nome", MySqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: What do you have so far, to accomplish that end? Update your question accordingly.

Comment: I just found out the answer. Thanks @joeframbach. This question wans't that stupid, didnt see way the downvote but ok.

Comment: Please update your question with the answer so the next person who finds this question will be helped. About the downvote, get over it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Just set it to `NULL`:

```
UPDATE table SET clube = NULL WHERE .....
```

Comment: First of all. Remove the downvote pls. It's no that simple. Remeber the condition that I have ? So, if its FALSE. I dont want to set it as null ... I need to do it using `MySqlCommand Parameter`

Comment: I didn't downvote. Please clarify the question with the `MySqlCommand` specifications.

Comment: Is this C#? I am sorry, I don't think I can help you here. I believe there is a `DBNull` type in C#. Perhaps that could help.

Comment: Yes it is C#.. OK ! Thanks anyway. Guess i'll just get a downvote for free u.u

Comment: I just found the answer, Thanks @bartFriderichs